# Attachment font and icon size

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I am adding attachments to a pdf file using IText like this:

```
document.add(new Paragraph(attac.get(index).toString()));  
            chunk = new Chunk("\u00a0\u00a0");  
            PdfAnnotation annotation = PdfAnnotation.createFileAttachment(writer,rect, "Click to open" , null,  
            attac.get(index),  
            attac.get(index));  
                        annotation.setColor(BaseColor.BLUE);

            annotation.setAppearance(new PdfName(""), template);

            chunk.setAnnotation(annotation);  
            document.add(chunk);
```

This produces a small paperclip icon on the created pdf.

How can i make the icon larger so it will be more visible? i wan its dimension to be bigger.

Comment: Try defining dcoument as Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 20, 20, 20, 20); then check once.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfAnnotation.html#createFileAttachment%28com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter,%20com.itextpdf.text.Rectangle,%20java.lang.String,%20byte%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) the second parameter `rect` sets *the dimension in the page of the annotation*. You can call the method with a larger rect, to make the icon larger.

Just for first testing make it appear really large (500x500):

```
PdfAnnotation annotation = PdfAnnotation.createFileAttachment(writer, new Rectangle(500, 500), "Click to open" , null, attac.get(index),  attac.get(index));
```

I hope this will make the icon bigger.

Comment: @haslex i tried it, but it wont change the size of the attachment icon.

Comment: What a pity. I have no alternative idea :(

Comment: @haslex  Thanks for your efforts :)